# Columnas responsive con bootstrap

Tags: responsive

Tengo una fila de 3 columnas, en cada columna va una imagen. Necesito establecer un tamaño a la columna y que sea responsive, es decir, que la imagen y los gutters sean siempre proporcionales. Estoy usando bootstrap.

Este es el código que tengo:

```
     <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row gx-2">
          <div class="col-4">
            <img src="assets/img/1.jpg">
          </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="assets/img/2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <img src="assets/img/3.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap provee un sistema de grillas responsiva dependiendo el tamaño de la pantalla del dispositivo, por ejemplo col-sm-2 para pantallas pequeñas, col-md-2 para dispositivos con pantalla mediana y col-lg-2 para dispositivos con pantallas grandes, teniendo esto en cuenta puedes usar las 3 para que tengan un comportamiento distinto dependiendo la pantalla de esta forma:

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-3"></div>
```

En el ejemplo de arriba, cuando use un dispositivo con pantalla grande la division ocupara una 3 columnas, con mediano ocupara dos columnas y con pequeño ocuapara una columna (de las 12 columnas con las que trabaja cada row de bootstrap), sm= small, md= medium, lg=large.

Te dejo mas información acerca de las grid de bootstrap en el siguiente enlace:[Documentacion grid bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)